# Azure DevOps integration in Sentry: Associate commits

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sentry

Did someone manage to integrate Azure DevOps in Sentry (sentry.io)? I stuck on "Associate commits with a Release" (see: https://docs.sentry.io/workflow/releases/?platform=browser#associate-commits-with-a-release)

I can not figure out a way how I can tell Sentry (by API) which commit ids are associated with a current release/deploy. How can I add a task to the pipeline which will post the commit ids to Sentry API? Or is there some other way to do it?

Comment: Have you looked into a Powershell task and then use the Azure DevopsAPI to query the data?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In azure devops, the `Powershell` task also support `curl`. So, you can execute the [api](https://docs.sentry.io/workflow/releases/?platform=browser#using-the-api) in powershell task of VSTS pipeline directly.

In release pipeline, there has a [pre-defined release variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#release-variables), it stores the **commit id** which is associated with the current release pipeline: `$(Release.Artifacts.{alias}.SourceVersion)`. Here `alias` is the **artifacts name**, and you can get it by getting `$(Release.PrimaryArtifactSourceAlias)`.

First, create variables like this:

[image]

Then you can apply the variable `$(id)` into that API, and execute the api in powershell task:

```
"refs": [{
 "commit":"$(id)"
 }]
```

Now, the `commit id` could be packed into the body of this api, and send to the Sentry server.

---

If there has multiple commits associate with this release, since the variable `$(Release.Artifacts.{alias}.SourceVersion)` I mentioned above only store the **latest** commit message, here you may need add additional scripts to get what you want by **Build id**.

In release pipeline, with $(Build.BuildId) you can get the corresponding **buildid** which associate with this release. And then, you could get the commits(changes) by using this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20changes%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/changes?fromBuildId={fromBuildId}&toBuildId={toBuildId}&api-version=5.1-preview.2
```

[image]

You could apply these powershell script into your task without change anything because this script is universal among powershell-ise, powershell command line and powershell task in VSTS.

```
$token = "{PAT token}"
$url="https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/build/changes?fromBuildId={id1}&toBuildId={id2}"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get
Write-Host "results = $($response.value.id | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

Now, you could get the list of commits which associate with the build and corresponding release.

Comment: My problem is, that a release has multiple commits (and therefore commit ids) and to use the sentry feature I have to associate them all to a release. But I can not figure out a variable that returns all commit ids.

Comment: It would be know problem to do this association on application side (backend code) if there is a possibility to read the commit ids of a build (by name) for example.

Comment: @DarthSonic. It can be achieved, but little confused. Either build or release, there's no directly variable can get all associate commits. In build pipeline, `Build.SourceVersion` can get the commit of build. BUT, it only restore the **latest commit**. To get all commits, you need use this [api](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20changes%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).  It will cause another issue: the commits between 2 builds not always equal with the commits which associate with current build. It depend on your actual build pipeline.

Comment: @DarthSonic. I update more details into my answer, please check that.