# Using Azure DevOps, get list of commits from GitHub in order to pass to Sentry as part of a release?

Tags: github, azure-pipelines, git-commit, sentry

I am using Azure pipelines to build and release my software through its GitHub integration. As part of monitoring, I am using Sentry to record exceptions, etc.

I want to use the "Suspect Commits" feature of Sentry (so it can point at commits that are likely to have caused a specific issue). For this to work, I need to send Sentry a release (just a version associated with a specific project) with a list of associated commits relating to it.

I've read this post:

[Azure DevOps integration in Sentry: Associate commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858386/azure-devops-integration-in-sentry-associate-commits)

And this one on GitHub:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/11127

And while both have (very different) approaches to getting a list of commits, they assume that one is using the Azure DevOps repositories feature. I have no repositories on my DevOps instance, so, though useful posts, they don't really help me directly.

In short - I need to list all the commits on GitHub associated with a specific release on Azure DevOps, so I can send them to the Sentry API.

Has anyone done this? How can I achieve that? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Neither of these linked options assume the repository is stored in Azure Repos. Both look at the Build and Release data only. The first relies on Azure Pipelines to associate the commits, the second creates a  clone of the repo and then allows the sentry-cli to compute the associated commits locally.

Comment: @jessehouwing - I have tried the powershell script - I am getting no commits between builds/releases even when I can see they were triggered by different GitHub commits.

Comment: To expand - I am getting a response (indicating a valid request), but the list of commits coming from the API is empty, @jessehouwing

Comment: It's possible that Azure Pipelines doesn't track this data for GitHub. And the other method of cloning and using sentry-cli?

Comment: I didn't try that, @jessehouwing - I don't see where it clones a repo? (and the comments indicate it assumes the code is run inside a git repo)

Comment: This maybe superfluous and rudimentary but have you checked this out?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#all-commits  You can wrap that in a powershell task and catch the json thats being returned for Sentry.  Just trying to help.

Comment: @jetstreamin - I did see that, however, where do I get the repositoryId? That is a Azure DevOps repository id, and I don't see how that would help with getting a list of commits from a GitHub repo.

Comment: @Oded if you look at the doc, it also name or id, that might work to just pass the name in

Comment: You can easily clone the repo yourself or add the repo as an artifact to your release pipeline.

Comment: @jessehouwing - thought about that, but wanted to avoid having to clone the whole repo (trying to have a *fast* release pipeline).

Comment: Just put it in a parallel stage and don't worry about it.

Comment: (The replier of first link coming...) How's your pipeline structure in Azure devops? CI + CD? Or just CD? And what's the trigger type? The get-changes api I mentioned in first link you shared does not suitable for github source. It only available for the git repos which in VSTS. BUT, in pipeline, it has build-in variable can represent the associated commit id from github. And just for one.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, @MerlinLiang-MSFT - this is a CI + CD pipeline. It is triggered on GitHub commits to the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comment, the [get-changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20changes%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) api which used in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858386/azure-devops-integration-in-sentry-associate-commits) ticket does not suitable for the build pipeline that **has github repos source**.

But, what fortunate is, we has fully feature support for github cloud. So here you can use another one to get such associate commits list, the one which does not be documented by us.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_traceability/runview/changes?currentRunId={build id}&__rt=fps&__ver=2
```

*Most of time, you can consider to catch some records from `F12`, when you find no way from documents we public. Above api can be got from F12 while you click on the `Changes` link in Build `Summary` page:*

[image]

---

I wrote a complete powershell script, which you can directly make use it in release pipeline to get commits id from its response body:

```
$token = "{PAT token}"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_traceability/runview/changes?currentRunId={build id}&__rt=fps&__ver=2"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get

Write-Host "results = $($response.fps.dataProviders.data.'ms.vss-traceability-web.traceability-run-changes-data-provider'.artifactsData.data.id | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

[image]

---

In release pipeline, we provide one built-in environment variable that you can directly get the corresponding triggered Build id: `$(Build.Buildid)`. And you can inject this into api to make the build id can be get automatically during the CI+CD process.

---

**Update on 3/4/2020:**

Based on the screenshot you shared in our discussion, the data structure on yours is for git repo (*not sure why, will dig that*) :

Please transfer the pipeline with YAML. Then trigger it and write the commits with the scripts I shared above. You will see commits data from the results of YAML.

Comment: Getting 401 Unauthorized for that URL.

Comment: @Oded 401 is a token error. Does the token you used is available?

Comment: It is available and works for other calls, for example with `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/changes?fromBuildId={fromBuildId}&toBuildId={toBuildId}&api-version=5.1-preview.2` - could this be a permissions issue with the token?

Comment: I've enabled all read options for the token and am still getting 401 for this call (when other calls with same token work).

Comment: @Oded This is different from the one you said just now. What about generate a new PAT by setting the scope to all? I did with such scope.

Comment: Full access token works (in that I don't get a 401), but the result is empty.

Comment: @Oded Great. Does the summary page of the build you used in that api having actual changes?

Comment: Yes it does - 1 commit.

Comment: @Oded.Just run again with one build that only contains 1 commit. I can get it successfully: https://imgur.com/a/urb548D. What about print out with `Write-Host "results = $($response.fps.dataProviders.data.'ms.vss-traceability-web.traceability-run-changes-data-provider'.artifactsData.data | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"`. Here it will print out the complete commit message https://imgur.com/a/GRtOmeA.

Comment: I get a completely empty response - Just `results = `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208908/discussion-between-merlin-liang-msft-and-oded).

Comment: The powershell script returns the same incomplete results as Microsoft's Get-Changes API  :(
I get the ".artifactsData.data" only for the first repository. So this is not working for builds that have multiple Git repos.