# Azure Devops RestAPI to access Resources in YAML pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

In Azure DevOps Multi Stage YAML Pipeline, under resources section I had defined 2 repo resources Demo2 and Demo3. I want to access the changes happening between the builds for the repo Demo2 and Demo3. In pipeline summary page, there is an option view changes, which gives the commits from the repo and I am trying to get that details via RestAPI.

I tried to find details via Azure DevOps RestAPI page and az devops CLI but can't find anything helpful, so reaching out here for help.

[image: Pipeline Summary shows the view changes]

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Demo2
    type: git
    name: 'Test/Repo2'
  - repository: Demo3
    type: git
    name: 'Test/Repo3'

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: Demo2
- checkout: Demo3
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Devops RestAPI to access Resources in YAML pipelines

I am afraid there is no such documented REST API to get the details via option view changes.

But we could try to use **<kbd>F12</kbd>** to grab the URL:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_traceability/runview/changes?currentRunId={Build Id}
```

Then we will get the feedback with `HTML` type, we could convert it the `Json` type, we could get some info about the commit:

[image]

If we need to check the context of the commit, we could use the REST API [Commits - Get] [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the details.

Comment: This worked, i was struggling to convert the HTML into PSobject and then i stumbled upon this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60453301/using-azure-devops-get-list-of-commits-from-github-in-order-to-pass-to-sentry-a and this worked like a charm.